# How can we share a Hash table between two different kernel modules

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, declaration, extern

Is it possible to share a Hash_table defined in one kernel module in another kernel module.

```
/*Hash table declarartion and definition*/
DEFINE_HASHTABLE(my_hash_table, HASH_TABLE_BITS);
```

I am populating this table in one module, however I would like to access this table in another module as well.

Does extern declaration work here. `extern DEFINE_HASHTABLE(...,...)`

Answer (score 3):

`DEFINE_HASHTABLE` is variable's *definition*. For *declare* variable (without defining it) use `DECLARE_HASHTABLE`:

```
extern DECLARE_HASHTABLE(my_hash_table, HASH_TABLE_BITS);
```

Note, that in the Linux Kernel you need additional steps for make variable defined in one module to be usable in the other one.

First, you need to export symbol from the module, which defined variable:

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(my_hash_table);
```

Second, until you build both modules in the single directory(with single makefile) you need to specify in the `Makefile`, used for compile other module, that, that it should use `Module.symvers` file from the first module:

```
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS := <dir-with-symbol-provider-module>/Module.symvers
```