# Why would a Linux kernel module symbol not be exported globally properly?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, insmod

We have written a number of kernel modules and many with exported symbols that all work fine except for 2 symbols (which is baffling). We have exported them as all the others but the 2 symbols are not globally exported once they are inserted into the kernel.

In our C code we have (in wdt.ko):

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(WDT_Enable);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(WDT_Disable);
```

If we run `nm` on the generated kernel object, they appear correctly:

```
nm wdt.ko | grep WDT
00000000 T WDT_Enable
00000000 T WDT_Disable
```

This should mean that those symbols are globally exported. Once we insmod the kernel object:

```
# insmod wdt.ko
# insmod apphandler.ko
apphandler: Unknown symbol WDT_Enable
apphandler: Unknown symbol WDT_Disable
```

If we look at the kallsyms:

```
# cat /proc/kallsyms | grep WDT
c12504dc t WDT_Enable  [wdt]
c12502d8 t WDT_Disable [wdt]
```

Once they are inside the kernel, they are not global.

We have confirmed that correct file is being inserted into the kernel and that the functions are visible in the same module, but we cannot explain why the symbols suddenly become local and not global like `nm` suggests.

Does anyone know where our error might be?

Comment: Global *visibility*, shown by `nm` and `/proc/kallsyms`, doesn't mean *availability* for other modules, which is controlled by `EXPORT_SYMBOL`, see e.g. this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32968237/3440745). Also, for make symbols, defined by one module, being available in another one, `EXPORT_SYMBOL` alone is insufficient. You need either build both modules in the same directory, or use `KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS` variable in the makefile for the second module: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32949236/3440745.

Comment: Yes - agreed with your comments, and as mentioned, our other symbols were all working. Our one C file where WDT was being defined did not include the header file below. We do build all the modules in the same place and we have a "common" build makefile template for each one.

Comment: I had a "similar" case in which the `devm_watchdog_register_device` function was undefined when compiling an out of source module of mine that uses this function  even thoug the `devm_watchdog_register_device` is exported as can be seen here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/watchdog/watchdog_core.c#L443 - .In my case, it was becuase the `CONFIG_WATCHDOG_CORE` was not set so yes. Setting it to `CONFIG_WATCHDOG_CORE=y` solved the issue (by adding it to the symbol table of the kernel modules).

Answer (score 1):

Ok - shortly after posting the question we noticed that our include paths were missing the module include:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
```

The code seemed to compile file without the `#include` being included and the compiler did not generate errors or complaints but the net effect was that the symbols where not available to subsequent modules.

Since including the header file the symbols indicated above are available to modules and the kernel is able to resolve and execute the code.

Comment: Add this information into your question post (via editing) instead of posting it as an answer (because it is not an answer actually).

Comment: Unfortunately it really did resolve our issue. I can't really explain why leaving out the header caused the effect, but including it made the symbols perform as advertised. There were no other changes made other than `#include`

Comment: It might work due to the additional cycle of recompilation. Try to remove and reproduce.

Comment: If this modification fixes the problem, what words `but had the above effect` mean?

Comment: There were many many many many many many recompilation cycles, and deleting, restoring, reverting, etc. before this question. The above effect was not being able to have the symbols available (i.e. the insmod error). After the `#include` the module inserted correctly and the functions where called correctly.